# Android studio | Dependency Management

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

Can anyone suggest, how can we add a dependency at build time in android gradle based on some condition like:

```
dependencies{
       if(someCondition){
           // add dependency
       } 
   }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this:

**Step1:** Declare a `boolean variable` in gradle at root level.

```
like: def someDependencyEnabled = true //This could be dynamically set.
```

**Step2:** Using this `boolean` variable we can apply a check like:

```
if(someDependencyEnabled){
    //Add some dependency
}
else
{
    //Add some other dependency
}
```

**Step3:** Define Different source set for different situations:

```
android.sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', someDependencyEnabled ? 'src/dependency_enabled_src' : 'src/dependency_disabled_src']
        }

}
```

where:
**'src/main/java'** : is the common src file which contain common code.

**'src/dependency_enabled_src'**: is the source folder that contain dependency specific code. which is further used by 'src/main/java'.

**'src/dependency_disabled_src'**: is the source folder that contain alternate code when particular dependency is disabled.

In my case I wrote same name classes, methods & package name in both folders (dependency_enabled & dependency_disabled src) and wrote methods with desired implementation in dependency_enabled_src & empty methods for dependency_disabled_src.